# Difference between `.sh` and `.csh`

Tags: software-installation, environment-variables, intel

I have just installed Intel Parallel Studio and would now like to set up system variables, so Terminal can find the compilers etc.

In [the installation guides](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522356) tell me to run some included set-up scripts or include them in my bash profile etc. That's cool.

It always says though, for example:

> Set the environment variables before using the compiler. You can use
>   the source command to execute the shell script compilervars.**sh** or
>   compilervars.**csh**.

However it doesn't explain the difference between the two variants anyway. I also am unable to find any comparisons of the two file extensions anywhere else online.

The only things I might infer is that the `.csh` files are Mac OSX specific, from the line:

> On Linux* and OS X*, the file is a shell script called compilervars.sh or compilervars.csh

I would like to know more details before running anything.

Comment: If your login shell is bash or a bash compatible variant, run the .sh file. If your login shell is tcsh or another c shell, run the .csh file. The only relevant differences for the Intel scripts are how environment variables are set in the different shells.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.sh` is indicative of a script for the Bourne shell (`sh`) or the Bourne Again shell (`bash`), which is generally a superset of its predecessor.

`.csh` is indicative of a script for the C shell (`csh`), which, being a shell, is largely similar, but significantly different as soon as you start doing anything much more complex than running a series of static commands.

Both shells are generally available on any POSIXy environment, and indeed both are often preinstalled, though `bash` (and its cousin `sh`) are a little more ubiquitous in my experience.

I say 'indicative' above, because the idea of a file extension doesn't technically exist and has no semantic or syntactical meaning.  A file could be named `script.steve` or `documentation.exe` or `include.h` and still actually be a shell script.  For more definitive confirmation, look at the first line of the file.  For a script designed to be executed directly, it should start with a shebang line, which starts with an octothorpe (`#`), a bang (`!`), and the path to the executable which should run the script.  For example:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: So in essence: use the `.sh` version if your login shell is an `sh` shell (`bash`, `ksh`) and use the `.csh` version if your login shell is a `csh` shell (`csh` or `tcsh`). On macOS, the default shell is a `sh` shell nowadays.

Comment: Thanks! I saw that I can run `man sh` to get the details of my default shell. I got back that it is **dash**. I also ran `man bash` and received a **bash** man-page. Which one is being used by default and is there any difference I should care about? I am clearly a beginner - doing nothing complex, as you mentioned. [I am on Ubuntu 16.04].

Comment: @DexterMorgan Both are `sh` shells. The default shell on Ubuntu is `bash`.

Comment: @DexterMorgan `man sh` won't give you the manual of your default shell. It will give you the manual of whatever shell is being used as `sh` on your system. On Debian-based systems (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint etc) that is `dash` by default. However, *your* default shell is usually set to `bash`, not `sh`. To see the name of your default user's shell, run `echo $SHELL`.

Comment: Yep, as you said it would be: `echo $SHELL` returns `/bin/bash/`. Thanks @terdon!